# splitting a field into two using linux cut

Tags: linux, cut

I have several fields in my log file and I have been able to transform them to CSV with the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=/home/MSC11/khanm/wwwp11dorganiser.co.uk_log
OUTPUT="/home/MSC11/khanm/output-$(basename $INPUT | cut -d'.' -f1).csv"
# field names
s=1
ip=
dt=
method=
target=
protocol=
statuscode=
reference=
echo -n "Processing..."
# empty output file
>$OUTPUT
# read input line by line
while IFS= read -r line
do
   # get data
    ip=$(cut -d" " -f1<<<"$line")
    dt=$(cut -d" " -f4<<<"$line")
    method=$(cut -d" " -f6<<<"$line")
    target=$(cut -d" " -f7<<<"$line")
    protocol=$(cut -d" " -f8<<<"$line")
    statuscode=$(cut -d" " -f9<<<"$line")
    reference=$(cut -d" " -f11<<<"$line")
    # write cvs formatted output
    echo "${s},${ip},${dt},${target},${method},${protocol},${statuscode},${reference}" >>$OUTPUT
    # update counter
    s=$(( ++s ))
done < "$INPUT" 
echo "done."
echo "Total ${s} line processed and wrote to $OUTPUT cvs file."
```

The variable "dt" is of the format 29/Nov/2007:20:42:09.  I want to split this into two.  One with the date of the format 29/Nov/2007 and the second with the format 20:42:09.  I have working around cut commands but I haven't been able to do that.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cut -d: -f1 <<< $dt
29/Nov/2007
cut -d: -f2- <<< $dt
20:42:09
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I just wanted to ask that the field dt is the 4th field in the line.  Would it be okay to use this code?

Comment: Yes, you can run the above in sunstroke and assign the output to new shell vars. Field numbers only refer to the current cut so will not interfere with your existing code.

Comment: I am absolutely new to Linux so forgive me for asking stupid questions.  Could you please explain how cut -d: -f1<<< $dt and cut -d: -f2- <<< $dt work?  And can you suggest me any good learning source?

Thanks again!!

Comment: this just means cut at :, the first part gets the first field, and the second part gets the rest (field 2 and onward to the end).